# How to tri-parse cell values to form polynomial expression?

Tags: vba, excel, math, functional-programming

EDIT: most revised code posted below.

EDIT: I am looking to let user enter polynomials such as: A(n) * X^n + A(n-1)*X^(n-1) + A(n-2)*X^(n-2) + ... + A(0)

I have Excel macro in progress to demonstrate Intermediate Value Theorem. User enters Degree in A2, Coefficient in B2.

Currently MsgBox can return first order polynomial in form Coefficient*x^Degree. I want MsgBox to be able to return more complex polynomials so user can confirm correct polynomial was entered.

Here is code:

```
Sub Function1()
MsgBox "Enter polynomial by terms."

counter = 1
counter = counter + 1
Degree = Cells(counter, 1).Value 'A2
Coefficient = Cells(counter, 2).Value 'B2
'   If cell value is null stop
If IsNull(Degree) = True Then
    MsgBox "IsNull(Degree)=True"
End If
If IsNull(Coefficient) Then
    MsgBox "IsNull(Coefficient)=True"
End If
If IsNumeric(Len(Trim(Degree))) = True And IsNumeric(Len(Trim(Coefficient))) Then
    MsgBox "Degree is numeric"
    If Degree Mod 1 = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Degree is integer"
    End If
End If
MsgBox Coefficient & "x^" & Degree
'   How repeat this process to show in MsgBox entire polynomial?
End Sub
```

EDIT: revised code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Function1()
Dim Polynomial As String
Dim Sign
Dim counter As Integer
Dim Degree
Dim Coefficient

While Cells(counter + 1, 1).Value <> "" And Cells(counter + 1, 2).Value <> "" '+1 because top row occupied by column A, column B titles. If cell is empty stop.
MsgBox "Enter polynomial by terms."
Degree = Cells(counter + 1, 1).Value 'A2
Coefficient = Cells(counter + 1, 2).Value 'B2
If (Coefficient < 0) Then Sign = " - " ' if coefficient negative
    Else: If Coefficient > 0 Then Sign = " + " ' if coefficient positive
End If
Polynomial = Polynomial & " " & Coefficient & "x^" & Degree 'concatenation string, list polynomial.
counter = 1
counter = counter + 1
Wend
MsgBox poly
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to provide examples of what you have and what outputs you desire. We don't have enough to work with

Comment: See "answer" below by Amine, I apologize, that "answer" has an example of what I want to be able to make happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a loop around what you've already written, and concat `Coefficient & "x^" & Degree` inside a `String` variable. It could look like this:

```
Dim poly as String
Dim sign as String

' Iterate over data cells:
while Cells(counter,1).Value <> ""
    ' What you're already doing...
    ' ...plus:
    IIf(Coefficient < 0, sign = " - ", sign = " + ")

    ' String concatenation:
    poly = poly & " " & Coefficient & "x^" & Degree
    counter=counter+1
Wend
' Finally:
Msgbox poly
```

EDIT: Also, if you want to check for empty values, use `If Cells(counter,1).value = "" Then ...`. `IsNull` is used to check if objects are empty; simple data types are initialized with `""` for `String` and `0` for numbers and thus will never trigger `isNull`.

Comment: This works perfectly and is more concise than original code.